# I got HTTP Error 403: Forbidden error when I check a list of urls

Tags: python, url, http-status-code-403

I'm new to python. I tried to check broken urls from a list of urls stored in a xlsx file. And the first several urls worked well, but then it stopped and showed "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". I'm not sure if it's the problem of "user agent". I tried several ways, but didn't work. Hope you can see which part of my code is wrong.

This is part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import time


file = pd.read_excel('tests.xlsx')

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/49.0.2')]

error_url=[]
for i in range(0,len(file)): 
    url=file.values[i][0]
    test = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    try :     
        opener.open(url)
        print(url+' : succeed')
        if 'scholarship' in test.decode() or 'award' in test.decode():
            print(" Yes")
        else:
            print("No")
```

The error is like this:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lme5h.png)

Comment: It seems like the site you connecting to doesn’t want you to do so. You may be making too many requests and they have blocked you.

Comment: A `403` generally means that you are trying to access something which you are not authenticated for. Do you think that you should have access to the resource you are requesting?

Comment: first use `print()` to display url which makes problem and check it manually in web browser. Maybe it doesn't work even in web browser. But problem can be user agent - some pages need real user agent, not short version `'Mozilla/49.0.2'`. Other pages may check other headers or need cookies.

Comment: @furas - Thank you for your advice. Yes, my goal is to find out those broken urls, I also think it might be the problem of user agent, do you have any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: first you can use page like https://httpbin.org/user-agent  to get real User-Agent from your browser and copy it to your code. Second use `print()` to display url(s) which makes problem. And then you can check this url in real web browser to see if it make problem. If it doesn't make problem in web browser then you can check in `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab 'Network`) what other headers sends browser to this page and try to use them in code. Not all headers will be needed so there is no need to use all of them in every request.